# OneSignal in Ionic Cordova: Can you get Player ID in app?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, onesignal

I'm using OneSignal in my Ionic Cordova app, and I want to get the device's Player ID in the app. Is there a way to do this? I haven't found anything in the [documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-sdk)